# Power shell Pass argument

Tags: powershell

I am passing $nextday and $currrentyear to the .exe which I am executing within my powershell script. It seems that the arguments do not pass, why?

```
$nextday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("M/dd/yyyy")
$currentgetyear = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy")

& "C:\tmt.exe" YEAR=  $currentgetyear DATE=  $nextday
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you use space between the words? See how it's parsed by the software:

```
[21:50:46] > & echoargs YEAR=  $currentgetyear DATE=  $nextday
Arg 0 is <YEAR=>
Arg 1 is <2013>
Arg 2 is <DATE=>
Arg 3 is <2.26.2013>
```

This however is parsed how I guess it should be.

```
[21:50:58] > & echoargs YEAR=$currentgetyear DATE=$nextday
Arg 0 is <YEAR=2013>
Arg 1 is <DATE=2.26.2013>
```

So my solution: remove the spaces, like this:

```
& "C:\tmt.exe" YEAR=$currentgetyear DATE=$nextday
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
& "C:\tmt.exe" ("YEAR={0}" -f (get-date).Year) ("DATE={0:M/dd/yyyy}" -f (get-date).AddDays(-1))
```

Bill